# Why scala.util.matching.Regex 'apparently' fails in Scala extractors?

Tags: java, regex, scala, pattern-matching, data-extraction

I'm using Scala extractors (i.e.: Regex inside in a pattern mathing) in order to identify doubles and longs, like shown below.

My question is: why Regex is apparently failing when employed in a pattern matching whilst it clearly delivers the expected results when employed in a chain of if/then/else expressions?

```scala
val LONG   = """^(0|-?[1-9][0-9]*)$"""
val DOUBLE = """NaN|^-?(0(\.[0-9]*)?|([1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]*)|(\.[0-9]+))([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?$"""

val scalaLONG   : scala.util.matching.Regex = LONG.r
val scalaDOUBLE : scala.util.matching.Regex = DOUBLE.r

val types1 = Seq("abc", "3", "3.0", "-3.0E-05", "NaN").map(text =>
    text match {
      case scalaLONG(long)     => s"Long"
      case scalaDOUBLE(double) => s"Double"
      case _                   => s"String"
    })
// Results types1: Seq[String] = List("String", "Long", "String", "String", "String")

val types2 = Seq("abc", "3", "3.0", "-3.0E-05", "NaN").map(text =>
    if(scalaDOUBLE.findFirstIn(text).isDefined) "Double" else
    if(scalaLONG  .findFirstIn(text).isDefined) "Long"   else    
    "String")
// Results types2: Seq[String] = List("String", "Long", "Double", "Double", "Double")
```

As you can see from above, `types2` delivers the expected results whilst `types1` tells "String" when "Double" is expected, apparently pointing out to a failure in the Regex processing.

**EDIT**: With help from @alex-savitsky and @leo-c, I've arrived to the following shown below, which works as expected. However, I have to ***remember*** to provide an empty argument list in the pattern matching, otherwise it gives wrong results. This looks *error prone* to me.

```scala
val LONG   = """^(?:0|-?[1-9][0-9]*)$"""
val DOUBLE = """^NaN|-?(?:0(?:\.[0-9]*)?|(?:[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]*)|(?:\.[0-9]+))(?:[Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?$"""

val scalaLONG   : scala.util.matching.Regex = LONG.r
val scalaDOUBLE : scala.util.matching.Regex = DOUBLE.r

val types1 = Seq("abc", "3", "3.0", "-3.0E-05", "NaN").map(text =>
    text match {
      case scalaLONG()     => s"Long"
      case scalaDOUBLE()   => s"Double"
      case _               => s"String"
    })
// Results types1: Seq[String] = List("String", "Long", "Double", "Double", "Double")

val types2 = Seq("abc", "3", "3.0", "-3.0E-05", "NaN").map(text =>
    if(scalaDOUBLE.findFirstIn(text).isDefined) "Double" else
    if(scalaLONG  .findFirstIn(text).isDefined) "Long"   else    
    "String")
// Results types2: Seq[String] = List("String", "Long", "Double", "Double", "Double")
```

**EDIT**: OK... despite *error prone*... it is an extractor pattern, which employs `unapply` behind the scenes and, in this case, we have to pass arguments to `unnapply`. @alex-savitsky is using `_*` in his edit, which explicitly enforces intention of dropping all capture groups. Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` matches the whole input, while `findFirstIn` can match partial input contents, sometimes resulting in more matches. In fact, `findFirstIn` will ignore your boundary markings `^$` outright.

If your intention was to match the whole input, put your `^` at the beginning of the regex, as in `val DOUBLE = """^NaN|-?(0(\.[0-9]*)?|([1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]*)|(\.[0-9]+))([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?$"""`, then the `types1` would match the types correctly.

EDIT: Here's my test case for your question

```
object Test extends App {
    val regex = """^NaN|-?(?:0(?:\.[0-9]*)?|(?:[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]*)|(?:\.[0-9]+))(?:[Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?$""".r
    println(Seq("abc", "3", "3.0", "-3.0E-05", "NaN").map {
        case regex() => "Double"
        case _ => "String"
    })
}
```

results in `List(String, String, Double, Double, Double)`

As you see, the non-capturing groups make all the difference.

If you still want to use capturing groups, you can use `_*` to ignore the capture result:

```
object Test extends App {
    val regex = """^NaN|-?(0(\.[0-9]*)?|([1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]*)|(\.[0-9]+))([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?$""".r
    println(Seq("abc", "3", "3.0", "-3.0E-05", "NaN").map {
        case regex(_*) => "Double"
        case _ => "String"
    })
}
```

Comment: You said "then the types2 would match the types correctly". But ``types2`` was already the correct result. I suppose you've made some confusion. Your answer helped me to do some more steps, but I'm not really following your line of thinking and/or the tests you've done.

Comment: @RichardGomes Right, I meant `types1`, let me edit the answer

Comment: Have you tested that? I've substituted the regex you provided and it's still giving wrong results. I will try with non capture groups also.

Comment: Yes, the difference is that I was testing with non-capture groups. I think this calls for an even more informative edit

Answer (score 1):

Since you defined multiple capturing groups in scalaDOUBLE, you'll need to provide matching number of arguments in your corresponding match-case, like in the following:

```
val types1 = Seq("abc", "3", "3.0", "-3.0E-05", "NaN").map(text =>
  text match {
    case scalaLONG(long)                 => s"Long"
    case scalaDOUBLE(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5) => s"Double"
    case _                               => s"String"
  })
// types1: Seq[String] = List(String, Long, Double, Double, Double)
```

You can examine the captured groups, as follows:

```
"-3.0E-05" match { case scalaDOUBLE(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5) => (d1, d2, d3, d4, d5) }
// res1: (String, String, String, String, String) = (3.0,null,3.0,null,E-05)
```

Comment: These arguments are not necessary. If omitted, Scala will match the input anyway, without populating the groups

Comment: @Alex Savitsky, you're right that `"-3.0E-05" match { case scalaDOUBLE => "Double" }` would work as well, except that having an additional `case _` catch-all as in OP's original match-case statement would unnecessarily trigger compiler warning.

Comment: Thanks @leo-c for you contribution to the discussion, raising the matter involving the arguments for capture groups. :-)